# Fragment is unstable in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a complete beginner in using Android Studio . Here in this code I am trying to implement a Fragment using a button imposed in the Toolbar .Basically, I want to display the fragment content when clicked on the add button.I want to take few inputs from the user  from the fragment update it to Firebase and receive it from Firebase and retrieve it to a recycler view. When I tried to execute the code given below, the fragments blinks and then the app stops working.Any alternative to apply my process would be appreciated.

This is my activity file..

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class history extends AppCompatActivity {



    enter code here

    EditText success;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private historyfrag historyfrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarhistory);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        ActionBar ab =getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayut);

        historyfrag = new historyfrag();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbarhistorymenu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.print:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Print", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.add:
                    setupfragment(historyfrag);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


            }



    }

    private void setupfragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayut,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }


}
```

This is the xml file of the activity...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarhistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:menu="@menu/toolbarhistorymenu"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="History" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarhistory" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Found this error in the Logcat

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.myapplication.history@2fb40c4 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
        at com.example.myapplication.historyfrag.onAttach(historyfrag.java:85)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2574)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:828)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class name to:

```
public class history extends AppCompatActivity implements YourFragmentClassName.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Inside fragment class you should have:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: What happens on  implementing the onrfragmentinteractionlistener ?

Comment: when you create a new fragment in android studio it comes up with a few predefined  methods. Fragment needs an interface to communicate with it's activity . Check documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#java . The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method. OnFragmentInteractionListener is just default listener if you do not use another one. In my project it is doing nothing but implementation fixes that exception which set in onAttach method - check it.

Comment: Thank-You for helping